# What get my FIAT currency when I deposit into a Crypto-Exchange Bank Account?

Tags: fees

Someone obviously gets my FIAT money when I deposit EUR / USD into a Crypto-Exchange bank account.

What happens to that? Who gets to keep it? How is it spent? Owners of the exchange?

Comment: sorry i can't comment , do can you explain more we need more detiles to helps you. you can edit you question .

Answer (score 1):

In theory, pretty much the same thing that happens if you deposit money at a bank for the purposes of trading stocks, bonds, and other currencies, etc. It is your money and is being held on your behalf so that you can make trades, etc. Banks make money on these deposits (depending on jurisdiction and account) by lending this money to others at interest (fractional reserve banking), charging fees, charging commissions on trades, and a few other ways. Thus, at least traditionally, the money is not spent by the bank; it is entirely yours, by you sometimes have to pay to perform certain actions such as trading or simply for them maintaining your accounts. Once you've paid the bank, the money can get spent however the bank sees fit, including paying dividends to shareholders of the bank.

*This is to extend the answer to deal with the question about depositing into the cryptocurrency exchange's account at a commercial bank*

The cryptocurrency exchange probably maintains an account with a [commercial bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_bank) for the purposes of receiving funds. The exchange can then withdraw the money and keep it safe or can leave it at the commercial bank to protect. The commercial bank does not know or care that you, the depositor, have a claim over the funds in the account. This is similar to how a commercial bank often maintains a balance at a [central bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_bank); the central bank does not track the customers of the commercial bank -- that's the commercial bank's responsibility. Similarly, the cryptocurrency exchange needs to keep track of its customers' accounts.

In order to break down what's going on when you make a deposit, we can use [double-entry bookkeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system). The exchange has one or more fiat cash balances (and also crypto currency balances, which operate on exactly the same principles here as for fiat). Let's just look at a single one of its fiat balances for simplicity.

## From your perspective

When you make a deposit, it doesn't matter, accounting-wise, whether you made it through a bank or you handed cash over to the exchange's owner.
The deposit results in your cash assets being credited (decrease in cash) and your balance with the exchange being debited (increase in the amount you hold at the exchange). Note that this is exactly the same thing that happens when you deposit money at a bank. You have no net change in assets. That is, you can now go and credit your exchange balance and debit your cash balance to recover cash from the exchange.

## From the exchange's perspective.

The fiat currency belongs is an asset balance (one of the five types of balances in double-entry bookkeeping). So when it receives cash, the exchange's asset balance gets a *debit* (the exchange has more assets), but it **simultaneously** gets a *credit* in its liabilities (increase in amount owed) because it must pay you that amount if you ask for it. The exchange can move the cash assets around as it pleases (within legal limits); it could invest it all in pork bellies, but that does not change the fact that it has a liability towards you for your deposit amount. So if the price of pork bellies drops to zero, the exchange still owes you the amount deposited. Alternately, the exchange could just leave the money in a bank account under its own control, which is probably safer than investing in pork bellies, so that it has a low risk of being unable to return your money if you withdraw it. And I think this is where your source of confusion lies: the fact that the account at the exchange's bank happens to be under the control of the exchange does not mean that the money is the exchange's to do with as it pleases. The exchange (if it is legitimate and properly set up) has a legal obligation to fulfill its debt obligations, which includes your deposit.

If the exchange wishes to profit from your money, it needs to turn YOUR assets into ITS assets. One way of doing that is to charge you a fee. In this case, its liabilities on your account are debited by the amount of the fee and its income balance is credited (increased) by the same amount. Profit!

Note that when you deposit money in a bank or exchange, your account is an asset to you but a liability to the bank/exchange.

It's quite possible I made a mistake here; I don't have a financial background. If there is an accounting whiz who can check this over and give it an edit if necessary, that would be awesome :)

Comment: Lungi, thank you for the answer. But here it is quite different.I am depositing money into the Crypto-Currency's Bank Account. It is not going to my own trading account at a bank ! That is the key difference.

Comment: It's actually not very different at all. The exchange you are using uses a traditional bank as a transaction processor/money transmitter. And, in all likelihood, the exchange maintains a balance at the bank just like a commercial bank maintains a balance at a central bank.

Comment: A commercial bank might have millions or billions of dollars at a central bank on behalf of its customers. As far as the central bank knows or cares, it's only got one customer: the commercial bank. However, the commercial bank keeps its own records so it knows how much money belongs to which customers and where it has physically stored the money. This applies to any business, really, that does business with a bank. A restaurant may buy goods and have accounts owing with many suppliers. The bank doesn't care. The restaurant keeps track of this.

Comment: Another more direct example (but perhaps more obscure) is a family office (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_office)   The family office company keeps its assets at a commercial bank on behalf of its clients, but the bank only ever "sees" the account ad belonging to the family office. A cryptocurrency exchange is exactly the same: just another customer to the commercial bank it uses for deposits, even though the funds are liabilities to the exchange (with you being the asset holder).

Comment: @NAD123ETH Now that I'm at a computer instead of on a phone, I've extended my answer above.